# Coconut milk ice cream — getting volume?

Tags: ice-cream, coconut, dairy-free, coconut-milk

I've made ice cream with full-fat coconut milk twice in my KitchenAid ice cream maker with OK results.

I've followed the instructions and have run the machine for the time suggested (about 20 minutes) and the ice cream mixture is ice cream like, but the volume has not increased by much.

My question is are my low-volume results because I'm using coconut milk, or can I run the machine longer and get more volume?

Thanks

Recipe:
1 can of full fat coconut milk ([Aroy-D Coconut Milk)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JMFCR0)
2 tablespoons honey
2 tablespoons cocoa power

Steps:

1. Mix ingredients together
2. Chill for 1 hour
3. Start ice cream machine (get it turning...)
4. Add mix to machine
5. Churn for 20 minutes
6. Serve

Comment: Can you post the recipe you're using? (Also, you say "coconut cream" once and "coconut milk" twice - what exactly are you using?)

Comment: Updated coconut cream to coconut milk and added recipe.

Comment: With the KitchenAid, can you increase the speed while churning? I lack experience, so I didn't want to put this as the answer. I want the KitchenAid ice cream bowl, so I can control the speed of the churn. With a faster churn, it should add air (which is volume). This is basically whipping air into the mix. They call that overrun.

Comment: I get better fluffier desserts from coconut milk/cream that isn't loaded with gums (stabilizers). That is counter-intuitive because I do add agar in making mousse and that traps a lot of air when I whip halfway thru gelling time. The goopy canned coconut stuff just can't hold a candle to the pure Tetra pack stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Try to decrease the fat percentage in the custard. Full fat coconut milk has a fat percentage of ~20%, hence the custard has about the same. Fat tends to make the ice-cream more heavy and "creamy". Ordinary ice-cream usually have a fat percentage around 10-16%, and even lower for gelato type ice-cream.

To decrease the fat percentage, add some liquid with low-fat.

Comment: If this is the OP's problem it's easy enough to fix - just use light coconut milk.

Answer (score -2):

You are simply freezing the coconut milk mixture.

First make a custard using the coconut milk; to do this scald the milk ie bring to just below boiling point whilst stirring constantly.

Meanwhile whisk 6 medium egg whites with 150g sugar until it becomes white and fluffy, then pour in the heated milk from the pan into the mixing bowl whilst whisking, this is to stop the eggs curdling.

Then poor the mix back into the pan and heat gently until the mix thickens, dont let it boil as this will curdle the custard.

After a while the mix will thicken and when it is thick enough to coat the back of a wooden spoon take of the boil. Then mix in whatever ingredients you want and pour into ice cream maker or into a freezable container and stir every 3-4 hours until fully frozen.

When I made this I added dessicated coconut to give it some texture and a bit more flavour. I then added the zest of 2 limes and the juice of 1.

Comment: A custard is made with egg yolks, not egg whites.